# timing constraints

Tags: fpga

I'm designing a ULPI interface for communicating with an USB chip.
But I have run into some problems regarding timing constraints.

Data is output at the rising edge of the clock, and sampled at the falling edge.

I can see (using Post-Route) that there is about 6ns "best case achievable delay" from clock rising edge to data out is valid.

If I want a smaller delay, should I rewrite my code and for example delay my clock until the rising edge fits with data out?

I know above solution is probably not good, since it will be both fpga device and route dependent... But what other options are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your data output register packed into an IO register?
The constraint in a UCF is: `INST "some_ff" IOB = TRUE;`
Or, you can use the map option `-pr b` which will pack inputs and outputs ([b]oth) into io registers.

This has 2 effects:

1. Locks down timing between the IO pin and the first/last D/Q pin of the FF (build to build consistency)
2. Maximizes clock-to-out performance (you can't get your Q any closer to the output pin).

*Edit:* The above recommendation applies to Xilinx toolchains. Other vendors likely have similar architectures, but the arguments/controls required to invoke the option differs.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a Xilinx device:

Check with FPGA editor as to where the flipflops have been located. Sometimes, if they are inferred from a non-top-level block, the tools will not pack them into the IOB, even if the UCF and options are set such that they should be.

As a workaround, adding an extra layer of flipflops on the top level can help.  Or you could possibly instantiate an ODDR2 block to force the issue and just connect the two data inputs to the same internal signal.